# Adding commands to VIM?

Tags: vim, command-substitution

I keep accidentally entering `W` instead of `w` as the command to save my changes. Is it possible to create a shortcut, alias, or command to write, and give it the hotkey of `W`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding the following to your `~/.vimrc` should do what you want:

```
command W w
```

If you also do this as part of `:wq`, I highly recommend using `:x` instead (it has the benefit of not re-writing the file when no changes have been made). Nonetheless, if you do, you can use this:

```
command Wq wq
command WQ wq
```

Comment: Usually, instead of `wq`, I use `ZZ` since then I don't have to hit escape.

Comment: If you want it to support all variants of `:w {file}`, `:w!`, etc., it's more work, but possible.

Answer (score 1):

You're lucky that your fat-fingering is about uppercase letters, as custom commands must begin with such. In the general case, the [cmdalias.vim plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=746) offers a way to create arbitrary aliases. This will also transparently handle all argument variants of `:w {file}`, `:w!`, etc.